# Rails is using PATCH when I would expect it to use POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I'm working on an application for assessing student work. When a student creates a new Post most of the time Rails uses the POST verb and life is good. However if the work is late and the Post has been scored as missing then Rails tries to create it (using the same route) with the PATCH verb instead of POST and creating the Post fails.

I error message that I see in Heroku's log is:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PATCH] "/users/55/posts”)
```

As far as I can tell the difference between the two situations is the existence of an instance of a Score when Rails decides to use the PATCH verb. The score model includes this line:

```
  belongs_to :post, touch: true
```

Could this be responsible for the difference in behavior? I thought it might, but there is not Post object created when the Score on the missing assignment is created (the way I checked this was to by typing `Post.where(user: score.user)` to `bin/rails c`. The result was an empty array.

Is there a way to force Rails to do a POST when it wants to do a PATCH?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to diagnose without more information. You can use `form_for @user, method: :post do |f|` to explicitly instruct Rails to use the POST method.

Comment: What information would be helpful? I wasn't sure what would be helpful to add.